# Which way to go with 'invalid assignment left handside' error: firefox or chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, variable-assignment

I have an object like this:

```
var myObj = {
    someProp: 1,
    updateObj: function (obj) {this = obj;}
}
```

So I am getting the `invalid assignment left hand side` in the line containing the function in `firefox` but not in chrome. So I am wondering which one should I choose?

Thank you.

Comment: `this` is a predefined keyword, you can't redefine it. Chrome gives the same error too, as any other browser will...

Comment: I just noticed that chrome also gives this error when I actually call the function, but not for declaration.

Comment: Yep, browsers are parsing the code differently, some check the syntax beforehand, some other just before use (a literal object is parsed every time it's used).

Comment: If you need to change `this`, please check [`apply & call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#call_and_apply) at MDN.

Comment: @Teemu: Thank you for your tips and the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like "self" instead of this.  You are trying to assign to 'this' which isn't allowed.

```
var myObj = {
    someProp: 1,
    updateObj: function (obj) {self = obj;}
}
```

If you are actually trying to change what the object is, just reassign it...

```
var obj = {
    someProp: 1
};

obj = {
   someProp: 2
};
```

...or do a more explicit update like:

```
var obj = {
    someProp: 1,
    updateObj: function(obj) {
       this.someProp = obj.someProp;
    }
};
```

Comment: `self` is a synonyme for `window`, please use `var`to avoid a conflict.